# Force download PDF instead of open it in a new tab using Cypress

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

Here are my steps:

1. Click a button
2. A report is generated and then downloaded.

I am using Cypress. After clicking the button, the file opens in a new browser tab, and I can't validate the content. Is there any way to force download the file instead of displaying the content in a new browser tab in Cypress?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the target attribute will prevent the browser from opening a separate new tab. maybe this can continue the download.

```js
cy
  .get('a')
  .invoke('removeAttr', 'target')
```

Also doing a cypress request may help.

```js
const element = doc.querySelector('[data-cy=orange-vcard]').getAttribute('href');
      cy.request({
        url: orangeVcardUrl,
        encoding: 'base64'
      })
        .then((response) => {
          expect(response.status).to.equal(200);
          // check for the response body here
        });
```

Ref: https://www.leonelngande.com/testing-file-download-links-with-cypress/